# Why there is no #include<QItemDelegate> in my delegate.h file?

Tags: qt, qitemdelegate

When i try to add a delegate file in my project, there is something wrong with my codes. I don't know why. My operations are as below.
[My operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzQYb.png)

[MyDelegate.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT3VV.png)

And the tutorial is as following:

```
    #ifndef MYDELEGATE_H
#define MYDELEGATE_H

#include <QItemDelegate>

class MyDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

    public slots;

};

#endif // MYDELEGATE_H
```

What is wrong with my file setting? Why do I lose the QObject *parent

Comment: QItemDelegate is a QObject subclass, so your class inherits from QObject through that already.

Answer (score 1):

This is specific of Qt Creator, so use your hands and complete class yourself, it's simple.

**UPD:**

When you change a *base class* in class constructor of **Qt Creator** you can just write from which class you want to ***inherit*** and **Qt Creator** do this. But what class (file) you want to ***include*** - this is hardcoded: `QObject`, `QWidget`, `QMainWindow`, `QDeclarativeItem`, `QQuickItem`, `QSharedData`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12493950)

Comment: @Mike, but this is the answer. I updated post, my apologies.